# Developing Application like Apple App Store

Tags: e-commerce, distribution

I've applied for internship program of a software company and I am expected to complete the task I am given by them. I write the description sent by them below. Could you please help me?

**"As you all know, in recent years applications have come into prominence for smart phones like iPhone, Android. The number of platforms like Apple App Store, Android Store on which the users can download applications and review products has increased.
What about you? What kind of platform would you create if you designed your own App Store?
You can define your dream App Store anyway you wish. Select just one stage of creating your App Store among "Analysis, Design, Implementation, Test" stages. And send it to us!"**

As you see, I am expected to complete one stage of creating my App Store and I want to choose "Implementation" stage.

What do you recommend? Is "Implementation" a good choice? What can I propose different from current Apple App Store.

Thanks in advance...

Here is Apple App Store: http://store.apple.com/us

Comment: I seriously doubt they expect you to create your own App Store as a qualification for the internship.  Surely all you have to do is describe how you would go about it.

Comment: Agreed, @tvanfosson. Implemnting an App Store equivalent is a significant task for an entire team of senior engineers, never mind as a qualification for a summer internship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can you complete the Implementation stage without first completing Analysis and Design? This assignment sounds like bait to see if you are willing to skip required stages and jump straight to coding, and that is a bad thing. Do the analysis stage.

Comment: +1 .totally agree with you.i used to do the same thing. learning from experience